# Difference between stateful and stateless iterators in Lua

Tags: lua

What is difference between stateless and stateful iterators in Lua, explain in detail please?When do we need to use stateless and when the other one? I need examples to understand the concept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First let's agree on a definition: (in Lua) an iterator is a *function*-like object that returns the next value in a sequence, every time it is called. I think it helps to rewrite the `for` iteration as done is Lua ref manual:

```
for itemlist in expression do block end
```

is logically equivalent to (pseudocode):

```
do
    local func, seq, controlVar = expression
    while true do
        local itemlist = func(seq, controlVar)
        if first of itemlist == nil then break end
        controlVar = first of itemlist

        block (which uses items in itemlist)
   end
end
```

where `expression` is a triplet of data (or a function call that returns such a triplet):

- `func` is the actual iterator function
- `seq` is the sequence being iterated over
- `controlVar` is the loop control variable

Iteration state is any state that could be needed to find the next item in the sequence being iterated over. A stateless iterator is therefore one where `func` does not contain any such state: you can call `func(seq, controlVar)` at any time, the return value will always be the same (if seq has not changed); it does not depend on what happened before the call.

As seen above, Lua supports *one* loop control variable. So in order for a sequence to be iterable via a stateless iterator, it must be possible to determine the next item in the sequence based on *one* loop control variable. I.e., it must be possible to figure out "next s item" from "(s, controlVar)" alone. The `ipairs()` generates an iterator that does this: `ipairs(s)` returns the triplet `(iterFunction, s, 0)`; the `iterFunction` can be given `s` and the index 0, and returns `1, s[1]`, then `2, s[2]`, etc (eventually nothing for a table of N items).

What if finding the next item in a sequence requires more than one loop control variable? Or depends on the state of other variables, which should be saved during iteration? Example:

- an endless iterator may need to keep track of "first" item so that once the end of sequence is reached, it can resume at first item;
- a graph iterator may need to keep track of "most recent sibling" in a depth first search so that once the end of a branch is reached, it can continue with next most recent sibling.

A stateful iterator holds state about the iteration so that the next item can be found. In Lua this is possible if the iterator function is a closure (a function with upvalues) or a functor (a table that behaves as a function, i.e. has a `__call` metamethod).  The up values (closure) or the data members (functor) could store the required state.

A stateless iterator can always be wrapped into a stateful iterator. For `ipairs`:

```
function statefulIpairs(s)
    local f, s, var = ipairs(s)
    return function() 
        local i, v = f(s,var)
        var = i
        return i, v
    end
end
```

This can then be called as

```
tbl = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
sip = statefulIpairs(tbl) -- sip is stateful iter specific to tbl
for i,v in sip() do print(i,v) end
```

A developer of a stateful iterator decides what capabilities the iterator has: the iterator's API may allow for rewind, inverting the direction, or other operations. This is even possible in the case of closures: additional parameters can be used to access the additional capabilities. Example, accept a third parameter which, when non nil, resets to beginning of sequence:

```
function resetableStatefulIpairs(s)
    local f, s, var = ipairs(s)
    local start = var
    return function(a,b,reset)
        if reset ~= nil then var = start; return end        
        local i, v = f(s,var)
        var = i
        return i, v
    end
end

sip = resetableStatefulIpairs(tbl) -- sip is stateful iter specific to tbl
for i,v in sip() do print(i,v) end
sip(nil, nil, true) -- reset it
for i,v in sip() do print(i,v) end
```

*Update* A neater example is how to generate a function iterator that accepts commands such that you can "...stop anywhere in the sequence and iterate over the rest of the sequence 3 times" (as requested by @deduplicator):

```
function iterGen(seq, start)
    local cvar = start or 1
    return function(cmd) 
        if cmd == nil then
            if cvar > #seq then return nil, nil end
            val = seq[cvar]
            cvar = cvar + 1
            return cvar-1, val

        else
            cmd = cmd[1]
            if cmd == 'rewind' then
                cvar = start or 1

            elseif cmd == 'newstart' then
                start = cvar
            end
        end
    end
end
```

With the above:

```
> s = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
> iter = iterGen(s)
> for i,v in iter do print(i,v); if i==3 then break end  end
1       1
2       2
3       3
> iter {'newstart'} -- save current as the new start pos
> for i,v in iter do print(i,v)  end -- continue till end
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
> iter {'rewind'}
> for i,v in iter do print(i,v)  end
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
> iter {'rewind'}
> for i,v in iter do print(i,v)  end
4       4
5       5
6       6
7       7
```

As demonstrated, there is nothing special about stateful iterators except for the fact that the state of iteration is inside the iterator, so as stated, it is up to the developer to expose desired functionality like rewind and newstart above. With stateless iterators,  there are no limits.

It would be a more natural API to design the iterator as a functor, since then the iterator "function" has "methods" which can be called, but it was an interesting challenge to create a commandable function.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your answer otherwise explaining it to a noob like me is really tough :) Thank you :)

Comment: @Simrankaur Glad this makes sense to you. Since you have enough points to upvote, you should try to either upvote answers or comment on what is not clear, in case author can fix -- this improves SO quality. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The difference between stateful and stateless iterators is simple:

Stateful iterators have internal state, so you cannot create them, run them for a bit, and then repeatedly request the end of the sequence using the same iterator. A good example is returned by `string.gmatch(...)`.

Stateless iterators in contrast are pure functions of their inputs, all state is external. The best known are returned by `pairs(a)` (returns `a, next` if no `__pairs` metamethod defined) and by `ipairs` (if no `__ipairs metamethod). If you want to repeatedly traverse the end of their sequence, just stash the arguments somewhere save.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand this :) Stateful iterators _cannot_ be repeatedly requested for end of sequence? Can you give an example of what you could do with `gmatch` if it were stateless rather than stateful? Also, how do you know that `gmatch` is stateful? If you could extend your answer (rather than comment), that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the first sentence about string.gmatch in the lua docs (version 5.2).

Comment: AFAICT (from testing), you can store the returned function from `gmatch` and call it anytime in the future, even if there are no references left to string (so there is a ref in the function).

Comment: Yes you can. What's your point? You cannot get it repeatedly, because the one and only object you saved has all state internal, its stateful.

Comment: You mean you can't traverse the whole sequence repeatedly with the returned iterator function. This is not a limitation of stateful iterators, just of the implementation of iterator provided by `gmatch` (see my answer).

Comment: Try to stop anywhere in the sequence and iterate over the rest of the sequence 3 times. Now compare.

Comment: Easy, as demonstrated in the update to my answer. This shows that your statement about not repeatable for stateful is actually wrong (or incomplete).

Comment: Pf, that's not a standard iterator any more, but a demonstration of turing-completeness for the language. Well, it was a fun discussion.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you found it fun too. Most important is to have fun  learning and sharing. Could have been fun to discuss what is a "standard" iterator ;) But SO Q&A not place for this, maybe a chat sometime.