# Trying to understand Custom Iterators

Tags: lua

im trying to understand the iterators, in many examples I founf something like this:

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)

   if currentNumber<iteratorMaxCount
   then
      currentNumber = currentNumber+1
      return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber
   end

end

function squares(iteratorMaxCount)
   return square,iteratorMaxCount,0 // why not return square(iteratorMAxCount,0)????
end  

for i,n in squares(3)
do 
   print(i,n)
end
```

First I dont understand the line I comment, and I dont find an easy example of how to do a Stateful Iterator and a Stateless iterator. Can anybody help me? thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this SO answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724092/difference-between-stateful-and-stateless-iterators-in-lua

Comment: I also suggest looking into: Programming in Lua: 7.1 – Iterators and Closures https://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html

Answer (score 2):

From [Lua Reference Manual 3.3.5](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5):

> A for statement like
>
> ```
>  for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end is equivalent to the code:
>
>  do
>    local f, s, var = explist
>    while true do
>      local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
>      if var_1 == nil then break end
>      var = var_1
>      block
>    end
>  end Note the following:
> ```
>
> `explist` is evaluated only once. **Its results are an iterator function,
>   a state, and an initial value for the first iterator variable.** f, s,
>   and var are invisible variables. The names are here for explanatory
>   purposes only. You can use break to exit a for loop. The loop
>   variables var_i are local to the loop; you cannot use their values
>   after the for ends. If you need these values, then assign them to
>   other variables before breaking or exiting the loop.

So squares() has to return a function (square) a state (iteratorMaxCount) and an initial value (0) in order to work with a generic for loop.

Read the reference manual, Programming in Lua.